# Was Rakata's "Force-enhanced" hyperdrive technology ever replicated (or something similar used)?

Tags: star-wars, hyperspace

We know that Rakatan empire in Star Wars EU was one of the earliest hyperdrive capable species, and their hyperdrive was powered by the Dark Side of the Force:

> The first interstellar space drive known to make use of hyperspace was developed by the Rakata, who built their Infinite Empire around technology using the dark side of the Force to travel through hyperspace. ([Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperdrive#History)).

**Has anyone used hyperdrive technology that was powered by the Force (any side) since the Rakata?**

It could have been a clone of Rakata's, or totally different, as long as it wasn't simply someone taking and using existing surviving Rakatan unit.

If not, was there an **explicit** in-universe explanation as to why the Force was never used to enhance Hyperspace travel? (the predictable "well the Rakata were screwed up via their use of Dark Side" doesn't seem to be plausible in a universe full of Sith, and assorted other Dark Force users).

Answer (score 1):

Around 200 years after the fall of the Rakata's Empire (the Infinite Empire) the civilizations from both the planets Correllia and Duro managed to build workarounds using the Rakata's force-based technology, making it common use in around twenty years or so. Even the Tionese managed to build a really basic form of hyperspace technology around the Rakata's force-only requirement. As for a reason why force sensitive hyperdrive was not further looked into, a huge problem the Rakata's had was because the hyperdrive relied on the use of the force, they could only travel to planets with high-force signatures, allowing other civilizations to take control of the planets in between. Hope this helps!